# How to create a launcher to group my Jumplists

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3

These are Jumplists I created with C# and .Net Framework: [Jumplist Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ4Dv.png)

I have 7 shortcuts in Taskbar which read data from their respective XML files to present a list of software with their icons. Each shortcut is destined for a kind of softwares.
I plan to group these jumplists into a UWP or WinUI3 app so I have just 1 shortcut and a cleaner taskbar.
Of course, they won't be Jumplist anymore in this new format. Probably will look more like a Windows 11 Start Menu but with a different layout.
I have no idea how to do this. And I'm not asking for a step-by-step tutorial.
I would like to get tips on where I can find orientations about how to achieve this.
In resume:

- Show a name: myApp
- Show an icon: myApp.ico
- Open myApp when clicked

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to implement such a feature in UWP apps. The Jumplist feature in UWP apps is used to provide quick access to recently or frequently-used documents.

Based on your requirements, I'd suggest you take a look at **[WinUI 3 app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app?pivots=winui3-packaged-csharp)**. WinUI3 app is a desktop C# .NET app with a WinUI-based user interface at the same time. You should still be able to use the same desktop API in the WinUI3 app and you could update your layout with a WinUI-based UI.

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right, WinUI 3 is a better solution for this

Comment: Oops, thanks for remembering me! have a good day